# How to read, edit, merge and save all csv files from one folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in Python, I'm trying to read all .csv files from one folder, I must add the third column (Dataset 1)from all files to a new .csv file (or Excel file). I have no problem to work with one file and edit (read, cut rows and columns, add columns and make simple statistics).

This is an example of one of my CSV files [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39MHN.png)

and I have more than 2000!!! each one with 1123 rows

Comment: have you tried xlwings? https://www.xlwings.org/ Also If it is literally just csv you can use cmd functionality  (copy *.csv new_file.csv) to merge the csv files

Comment: please take the [tour], read about [ask] and revise your question with a [mcve].

Comment: So for your output, you want a single file with 2000 * 1123 rows all containing a single column derived from Dataset 1?

Comment: create a new empty Data Frame to hold your final output. Read each file into a pandas DataFrame, append the third column from *each* into the final dataframe. Then dump that back to CSV.

Comment: @Web Head, that is what I want.

Comment: @ David Zemens can you give me an example of a code or where to look for use append??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly easy with something like the `csv` library, if you don't want to get into learning dataframes.

```
import os
import csv

new_data = []
for filename in os.listdir('./csv_dir'):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        with open('./csv_dir/' + filename, mode='r') as curr_file:
            reader = csv.reader(curr_file, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                new_data.append(row[2]) # Or whichever column you need

with open('./out_dir/output.txt', mode='w') as out_file:
    for row in new_data:
        out_file.write('{}\n'.format(row))
```

Your new_data will contain the 2000 * 1123 columns.

This may not be the most *efficient* way to do this, but it'll get the job done and grab each CSV. You'll need to do the work of making sure the CSV files have the correct structure, or adding in checks in the code for validating the columns before appending to `new_data`.

Comment: Thanks, @Web Head, but it generates an empty .txt file, do you have any idea?

Comment: @WNSL Yes, because I made a typo in the first `open` statement. Let me update it.

Comment: @ Web Head there is an error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @WNSL Did you replace the directories in the example with your own actual directories? csv_dir and out_dir are placeholders.

Comment: @ Web Head Yes I replace it

Comment: My example works with my local test folder and test .csv files. I can't see any reason it should be failing unless your environment or implementation are not set up correctly. Are all the files actually .csv files, or do they have a different extension containing CSV data? Are you using an absolute path instead of a relative path? If not, your relative path is likely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
csv_file = csv.reader(open(path, "r",), delimiter=",")
csv_file1 = csv.reader(open(path, "r",), delimiter=",")
csv_file2 = csv.reader(open(path, "r",), delimiter=",")
```

and then read like

```
for row in csv_file:
```

*your code here*

```
for row in csv_file1:
```

*your code here*

```
for row in csv_file2:
```

*your code here*